# Mixing Python and C++ source files in pybind11

Tags: python, c++, setuptools, pybind11

I am using PyBind11 to make a Python project.

My directory structure looks a like this:

```
./
  my_pkg/
    __init__.py
    func1.py
    func2.py
```

My C++ code looks like this:

```
int myfunc(){
  return 1;
}

PYBIND11_PLUGIN(cppmodule) {
  py::module m("cppmodule", "My cpp module");

  m.def("myfunc",&myfunc,"This does stuff");

  return m.ptr();
}
```

And my `setup.py` looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import glob

ext_modules = [
  Extension(
    "cppmodule",
    glob.glob('src/*.cpp'),
    include_dirs       = ['lib/include', 'lib/pybind11/'],
    language           = 'c++',
    extra_compile_args = ['-std=c++17'],
    define_macros      = [('DOCTEST_CONFIG_DISABLE',None)]
  )
]

setup(name = 'bob',
  version      = '0.1',
  description  = 'A package about shrimp',
  url          = 'http://github.com/shrimp',
  author       = 'Bob',
  author_email = '',
  license      = 'MIT',
  ext_modules  = ext_modules
)
```

Now, if I runn

```
python setup.py install
```

everything compiles.

But here's the odd part, later, I can run `import cppmodule` but not `import bob`. Or, with other fiddling, sometimes I can run both.

What I have not figured out how to do, but what I would like to do, is to have the C++ code incorporated into the `bob` module the same way `func1` and `func2` will be, so that I can type `bob.myfunc()` in Python.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried exposing those functions in `__init__.py`?

Comment: @krassowski: If I tell setup not to build the C++ stuff, then the functions expose automatically. I think two packages are getting declared and PyBind is taking precedence. But I will check on your suggestion shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to modify the code in `setup.py` to look like:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages

setup(name = 'bob',
  version      = '0.1',
  description  = 'A package about shrimp',
  url          = 'http://github.com/shrimp',
  author       = 'Bob',
  author_email = '',
  license      = 'MIT',
  packages     = find_packages(),
  ext_modules  = ext_modules
)
```

Comment: currently having the same problem ... using this answer, are you able to call  `bob.myfunc() ` now or do you have two packages installed now?

Comment: @BenjaminMaier: I see that I've answered the question less clearly than I could have. What I do now when I want a package named `bob` is to compile the pybind11 code into a package named `_bob` and then in `__init__.py` I import a bunch of stuff from `_bob` to make it available in `bob`.